# About orthogonal complement in Gilbert Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications 2nd Edition"

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, direct-sum

[image]

I am reading Gilbert Strang's "Linear Algebra and its Applications 2nd Edition".

On p.137(3.4 The PSEUDOINVERSE AND THE SINGULAR VALUE DECOMPOSITION), he wrote "***any vector can be split into two perpendicular pieces, its projection onto the row space and its projection onto the nullspace***".

I cannot find the proof of the above fact in his book.

I think he didn't prove the above fact in his book, but he used the fact in his book.

By the way, I think he proved the row space and nullspace of $A$ are orthogonal complements in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Am I correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because if $Ax = 0$ for $x$ in the nullspace, then each component of $Ax$ must be zero. But the components $[Ax]_j = 0$ corresponds to the dot product of the $j$-th row and $x$, which makes $x$ perpendicular to the entire row space. Therefore, the row space and the null space of $A$ are perpendicular.

Comment: also, any element of the orthogonal complement of the row space must be in the nullspace, and so comes the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I cannot understand why $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as $x = y + z, y \in R(A), z \in Null(A)$.

Comment: the validity of the decomposition is nicely proven below by tchappy. The main idea is to show that $\textrm{dim} R(A) + \textrm{dim} N(A) = n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix.
Let $R(A)$ be the row space of $A$.
Let $N(A)$ be the null space of $A$.
$\dim R(A) = r$, where $r$ is the rank of $A$.
$\dim N(A) = n - r$.
We can construct an orthonormal basis $v_1, \cdots, v_r$ of $R(A)$.
We can construct an orthonormal basis $w_1, \cdots, w_{n-r}$ of $N(A)$.
Then, the vectors $v_1, \cdots, v_r, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-r}$ are orthonormal because $R(A)$ and $N(A)$ are orthogonal.
So, the vectors $v_1, \cdots, v_r, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-r}$ are linearly independent.
Because $\#\{v_1, \cdots, v_r, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-r}\} = n$, $v_1, \cdots, v_r, w_1, \cdots, w_{n-r}$ are an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then we can write as $x = a_1 v_1 + \cdots, a_r v_r + b_1 w_1 + \cdots + b_{n-r} w_{n-r}$, where $a_i, b_j \in \mathbb{R}$.
$a_1 v_1 + \cdots, a_r v_r \in R(A)$ and $b_1 w_1 + \cdots + b_{n-r} w_{n-r} \in N(A)$.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you